# Getting specific DOM element from a set having same class

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML page which may contain hundreds of buttons. Each button has the same class but each one has a different id. I am creating the buttons using a loop. It is guaranteed that each button has unique id.

When any of these buttons is clicked I want to know the id of the button

eg. (I have only showed 2 buttons here)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.btn').click(function() {
                    alert($('.btn').attr("id"));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn" id="1">Button1</button>
        <button class="btn" id="2">Button2</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

but i always get the id of the first button in the page even when i click the second button

How to get the id of the specific button which was clicked?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `$('.btn').attr("id")` to `this.id` and you're done.